# Parse the large test files using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am looking to parse a space delimited input text file using awk. The column code can have more than one row for each group. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Input File:

```
TR 1   
Action   

Success/Failure 
8.1.1.1   RunOne   80   48
8.1.1.2   RunTwo   80   49
8.1.1.3   RunThree   100   100
8.1.1.4   RunFour   20   19
8.1.1.5   RunFive   20   20
Action Time   16:47:42
Action2   

Success/Failure 
8.1.2.1   RunSix   80   49
8.1.2.2   RunSeven   80   80
8.1.2.3   RunEight   80   80
Action2 Time   03:26:31

TR 2    
Action

Success/Failure
8.1.1.1   RunOne   80   48
8.1.1.2   RunTwo   80   49
8.1.1.3   RunThree   100   100
8.1.1.4   RunFour   20   19
8.1.1.5   RunFive   20   20
Action Time   16:47:42
Action2   

Success/Failure 
8.1.2.1   RunSix   80   49
8.1.2.2   RunSeven   80   80
8.1.2.3   RunEight   80   80
Action2 Time   03:26:31
```

Desired output file

```
------------------
s.no  Runno   Runname val1 val2  %val1&val2
1.    8.1.1.1 Runone  160  96    %       #val1 and Val2 should display as sum of TR1&TR2
2.    8.1.1.2 Runtwo  160  98
3.    8.1.1.3 Runthree 200 200
4.    8.1.1.4 RunFour 40 38
.......
```

and also find no of occurrences of Each Runname from each TR 1(TestRun)

Code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # You can customize this to change your output layout based on your preference.
    format = "%-10s%-7s%-5s%-8s\n”
    printf format, “Runno”, “Runname”, “Val1”, “Val2”
}
++i==2{
    l = $1
}
i>100{
    if (/^[[:blank:]]*$/) {
        i = 0
    } else if (NF > 1) {
        printf format, l, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
        p1=$1; p2=$2; p3=$3; p5=$5
    } else {

        printf format, l, p1, p2, p3, $1, p5
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What are the requirement to get to your desired input ? Why are there only 8.1.1.X's ?

Comment: Hi, this is output file for one of the test. and the file has Different Iteration (TR 1 and TR 2...). I have to parse the file and to display the Total Number of Runno, Runname for each Iteration.  Runno can be repeat multiple times for each iteration. Runno Start with 8.1.1.X;s only. I need to split/Parse the file and display in tabular column as mentioned above.

Comment: echo “Enter Number:”
read  n1
awk '/^$/ {ca=""; cp=""} /^#/ {ca=ca " " $0} /^$n1/ && ca {cp=ca; ca=""} /^$n1/ {print $0 " " cp}’ Please suggest me how to get the value from inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you a starting point. ***Note***: the output is not sorted, and missing the header and the first column from the output, but I'm leaving that to you!

```
awk '/^8\./ { a[$1 " " $2] += $3 ; b[$1 " " $2] += $4 } 
     END { for (k in a) { 
             printf("%s %i %i\n",k,a[k],b[k]) 
         } 
    }' INPUTFILE
```

1. With `/^8\./` it work only on the relevant lines
2. `a[$1 " " $2] += $3 ; b[$1 " " $2] += $4` for the relevant lines store and increment the third and fourth columns
3. finally print the relevant data by iterating through the `a` array and get the data from the `b` array as well.

Comment: The `1` and `2` in the first line aren't needed

Comment: @Jidder, you are right of course. I had copied an older version :-)

Comment: @Jidder, shame on me :-)

Comment: awk '/^$/ {ca=""; cp=""} /^#/ {ca=ca " " $0} /^8.1.1.1/ && ca {cp=ca; ca=""} /^8.1.1.1/ {print $0 " " cp}'<file Name>. Please suggest me that how to use input value for the above code.

Comment: echo “Enter Number:” read n1 awk '/^$/ {ca=""; cp=""} /^#/ {ca=ca " " $0} /^$n1/ && ca {cp=ca; ca=""} /^$n1/ {print $0 " " cp}’ Please suggest me how to get the value from inputs

Comment: Hi, this is output file for one of the test. and the file has Different Iteration (TR 1 and TR 2...). I have to parse the file and to display the Total Number of Runno, Runname for each Iteration. Runno can be repeat multiple times for each iteration. Runno Start with 8.1.1.X;s only. I need to split/Parse the file and display in tabular column as mentioned above.