# How do i parse the large file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am beginner for Linux. I have the following flat file test.txt

```
Iteration 1   
Telephony   


Pass/Fail

5.1.1.1   voiceCallPhoneBook   50   45
5.1.1.4   voiceCallPhoneHistory   50   49
5.1.1.7   receiveCall   100   100
5.1.1.8   deleteContacts   20   19
5.1.1.9   addContacts   20   20
Telephony   16:47:42
Messaging   


Pass/Fail

5.1.2.3   openSMS   50   49
5.1.2.1   smsManuallyEntryOption   50   50
5.1.2.2   smsSelectContactsOption   50   50
Messaging   03:26:31
Email   


Pass/Fail

Email   00:00:48
Email   


Pass/Fail

Email   00:00:40
PIM   


Pass/Fail

5.1.6.1   addAppointment   5   0
5.1.6.2   setAlarm   1   0
5.1.6.3   deleteAppointment   5   0
5.1.6.4   deleteAlarm   1   0
5.1.6.5   addTask   1   0
5.1.6.6   openTask   1   0
5.1.6.7   deleteTask   1   0
PIM   00:03:06
Multi-Media   

teration 2   
Telephony   


Pass/Fail

5.1.1.1   voiceCallPhoneBook   50   47
5.1.1.4   voiceCallPhoneHistory   50   50
5.1.1.7   receiveCall   100   100
5.1.1.8   deleteContacts   20   20
5.1.1.9   addContacts   20   20
Telephony   04:02:05
Messaging   


Pass/Fail

5.1.2.3   openSMS   50   50
5.1.2.1   smsManuallyEntryOption   50   50
5.1.2.2   smsSelectContactsOption   50   50
Messaging   03:20:01
Email   


Pass/Fail

Email   00:00:47
Email   


Pass/Fail

Email   00:00:40
PIM   


Pass/Fail

5.1.6.1   addAppointment   5   5
5.1.6.2   setAlarm   1   1
5.1.6.3   deleteAppointment   5   5
5.1.6.4   deleteAlarm   1   1
5.1.6.5   addTask   1   1
5.1.6.6   openTask   1   1
5.1.6.7   deleteTask   1   1
PIM   00:09:20
Multi-Media
```

I want to count the number of occurrences for specific word in the file Eg: if i search with "voiceCallPhoneBook" it's display as 2 times.

i can use

```
cat reports.txt | grep "5.1.1.4" | cut -d' ' -f1,4,7,10 |
```

after running this script i got output like below

```
5.1.1.4 voiceCallPhoneBook  50  45
5.1.1.4 voiceCallPhoneBook  50  47
```

It is very large file and i want to make use of loops with bash/awk scripts and also find the average of SUM of 3rd and 4th column value. i am struggling to write in bash scripts. It would be appreciated someone can give the solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: @4aRk Kn1gh7:  Hi Please find the code which i have written        awk '{print $4}’ report5.txt > temp_file
declare -a array
while read line
do
        if [[ ${array["$line"]} ]]; then
          array["$line"]=$(( ${array["$line"]} + 1 ))
        else
          array["$line"]=1
        fi
done < temp_file

for k in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "$k ${array[$k]}"
done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will search for lines containing 5.1.1.4
Make a tally of the 3rd and 4th columns
Then print them all out

```
awk '/^5\.?\.?\.?/ {a[$1" " $2] +=$3 ; b[$1" " $2] +=$4 }
END{ for (k in a){
      printf("%-50s%-10i%-10i\n",k,a[k],b[k])}
}' $1
```

Duplicate from earlier today is here [Parse the large test files using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258532/parse-the-large-test-files-using-awk/24258935#comment37481073_24258935)

With headers avg and Occurence count and formatted a bit neater for easier reading :)

```
awk 'BEGIN{
            printf("%-50s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n","Name","Col3 Tot","Col4 Tot","Ocurr")
}

/^5\.?\.?\.?/ {
        count++
        c3 = c3 + $3
        c4 = c4 + $4
        a[$1" " $2] +=$3
        b[$1" " $2] +=$4
        c[$1" " $2]++
}

END{
        for (k in a)
                {printf("%-50s%-10i%-10i%-10i\n",k,a[k],b[k],c[k])}

                print "col3 avg: " c3/count "\ncol4 avg: " c4/count
}' $1
```

Comment: remove `\.4` from the search

Comment: Thank you for the help. but i have value 5.1.2.1, 5.1.4.1, 5.1.5.1, 5.2.3.1 ... in the file. in this case how do i get the count? Since the value 5.1.2.1, 5.2.3.1 has many occurrences (1000)in the file. The only thing is the value always start with "5" only.. please suggest.

Comment: is it always 4 numbers ?

Comment: @user3749924 Changed the answer to print for all of them now :)

Comment: @user3749924 What sort of average do you want ? Of all of them or avg of specific 5.x.x.x

Comment: Thank you much. after executing the script i got the result  and the number starts with 5.1.6.5, but it should starts with 5.1.1.1                                                                Name                                              Col3 Tot  Col4 Tot  Ocurr     
5.1.6.5 addTask                                   14        12        14        
5.1.7.13 closeMusicPlayer                         14        14        14        
5.1.6.6 openTask                                  14        12        14

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
c3 = 0
c4 = 0
count = 0
}

/voiceCallPhoneBook/{
    c3 = c3 + $3;
    c4 = c4 + $4;
    count++;
}

END{
 print "column 3 avg: " c3/count
 print "column 4 avg: " c4/count
}
```

1) save it in a file for example countVoiceCall.awk

2) awk -f countVoiceCall.awk sample.txt

output:

```
column 3 avg: 50
column 4 avg: 46
```

Briefly explain:

```
a.    BEGIN{...} block uses for variables initialization
b.    /PATTERN/{...}  blocks uses to search your keyword, for example "voiceCallPhoneBook"
c.    END{...} block uses for print the results
```

Comment: @Hafizhan: Thanks. but How do i get for multiple occurrences? since the number 5.1.1.4 is repeating multiple times(1000 times) in a file. how do i fetch all 1000 occurrences and average it.

Comment: if you want to display them, add `print $0` to the `/PATTERN/{...} block`.  the `c3 = c3 + $3`  is to accumulate all column3 values, which is the sum of all lines matches pattern "voiceCallPhoneBook"

Comment: awk processes your input file line by line, as we provide specific pattern, it will only accumulate column 3 and column 4 of lines which matches the given pattern, it does not matter how many occurrences, does it make sense?